# How to loop through bootsrap modals with angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

My component.ts file have an array:

```
dummyData = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

I want to loop through this array while creating 3 modals that show 1, 2 and 3.

my html:

```
    <div *ngFor="let data of dummyData">
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{data}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My guess is that I somehow have to create individual id and data-target values for every modal. But I don't know how to do that. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: ditch jQuery, and use ng-bootstrap. You'll have a modal service nicely integrated with Angular. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: ^^ great idea, jQuery in angular is not good.

Comment: What sets `{{ data }}`? If clicking a button sets data and opens the modal, you certainly don't need a modal element per button. I do this all the time with Bootstrap modals in Angular apps

Answer (score 0):

If sticking to bootstrap

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dummyData">
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{data}}">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{data}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{data}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Giving each button and modal a unique id based on the contents of each array element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with vanilla Bootstrap is that you can't loop over with *ngFor and use string interpolation in your id, you'll get an error that bootstrap can't identify the element.

You'll need to use [ngBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) BUT if you're looking to customise the way it looks, you'll get a headache very quick. I'd recommend using [Material](https://material.angular.io/) as it was build for and by the Angular team which makes it a real treasure to work with.

Comment: Of course, you can build your own modal component and use Bootstrap classes over it. That it completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the exact same task and have completed it successfully with the help of [attr.data-target] and [attr.id] directives.

I've edited your HTML and here's the complete solution:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dummyData; let i = index">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button  type="button" [attr.id]="'triggerModalbutton-' + i"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
    [attr.data-target]="'#exampleModal-' + i">Launch demo modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade"  [attr.id]="'exampleModal-' + i" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        {{data}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```